# Summing together multiple columns in a multiindex dataframe and then adding column with the outcome

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

As the title suggests, I have a multi-index df that I want to group. Check if some conditions are met and later calculate a total score in an additional column. Then I would like to rank according to this score. The solution I have would be quite complicated as I have to recreate a compatible df (for example for df.update ()).
My problem arises from the fact that pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum doesn't have the axis keyword like pandas.DataFrame.sum.

Minimal example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
dd={'aavg': {
(Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'), 277, 403): 0.0694,
(Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'), 278, 403): 0.09393,
(Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'), 277, 415): 0.148286,
(Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'), 278, 415): 0.118842,
(Timestamp('2021-02-04 00:00:00'), 278, 403): 0.078156,
(Timestamp('2021-02-04 00:00:00'), 277, 415): 0.11675,
(Timestamp('2021-02-04 00:00:00'), 278, 415): 0.126452,
(Timestamp('2021-02-05 00:00:00'), 277, 415): 0.147857,
(Timestamp('2021-02-05 00:00:00'), 278, 415): 0.107894,
(Timestamp('2021-02-05 00:00:00'), 277, 403): 0.1245,
(Timestamp('2021-02-05 00:00:00'), 278, 403): 0.070652,
(Timestamp('2021-02-08 00:00:00'), 277, 415): 0.12475,
(Timestamp('2021-02-08 00:00:00'), 278, 415): 0.11235,
(Timestamp('2021-02-08 00:00:00'), 277, 403): 0.3435,
(Timestamp('2021-02-08 00:00:00'), 278, 403): 0.071826,
(Timestamp('2021-02-09 00:00:00'), 277, 415): 0.091,
(Timestamp('2021-02-09 00:00:00'), 278, 415): 0.116125,
(Timestamp('2021-02-09 00:00:00'), 277, 403): 0.057,
(Timestamp('2021-02-09 00:00:00'), 278, 403): 0.075733},
'acnt': {
(Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'), 277, 403): 5,
(Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'), 278, 403): 71,
(Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'), 277, 415): 7,
(Timestamp('2021-02-03 00:00:00'), 278, 415): 95,
(Timestamp('2021-02-04 00:00:00'), 278, 403): 90,
(Timestamp('2021-02-04 00:00:00'), 277, 415): 4,
(Timestamp('2021-02-04 00:00:00'), 278, 415): 115,
(Timestamp('2021-02-05 00:00:00'), 277, 415): 7,
(Timestamp('2021-02-05 00:00:00'), 278, 415): 123,
(Timestamp('2021-02-05 00:00:00'), 277, 403): 2,
(Timestamp('2021-02-05 00:00:00'), 278, 403): 92,
(Timestamp('2021-02-08 00:00:00'), 277, 415): 4,
(Timestamp('2021-02-08 00:00:00'), 278, 415): 60,
(Timestamp('2021-02-08 00:00:00'), 277, 403): 2,
(Timestamp('2021-02-08 00:00:00'), 278, 403): 46,
(Timestamp('2021-02-09 00:00:00'), 277, 415): 6,
(Timestamp('2021-02-09 00:00:00'), 278, 415): 88,
(Timestamp('2021-02-09 00:00:00'), 277, 403): 3,
(Timestamp('2021-02-09 00:00:00'), 278, 403): 60}}
ndf=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd,orient='columns')
ndf.index.set_names(['adate','filter_id','tr_id'],inplace=True)
print(ndf)
d = ndf.sort_index(level=0)

d['aavg_r5'] = d['aavg'].groupby(['filter_id','tr_id'],group_keys=False).rolling(5).mean() #weekly mean (trend)
d['aavg_diff'] = d['aavg'].groupby(['filter_id','tr_id'],group_keys=False).diff() #absolute change
d['aavg_pctc'] = d['aavg'].groupby(['filter_id','tr_id'],group_keys=False).pct_change() #relative change

last = d.index.levels[0].max()
l= d.loc[(last,slice(None),slice(None)),:].dropna()

l['s1']=(l['aavg_diff'].abs() > 0.1).astype(int)
l['s2']=(l['aavg_pctc'].abs() > 0.01).astype(int)
l['s3']=(((l['aavg_r5']-l['aavg'])/l['aavg_r5']).abs() > .1).astype(int)

### sum score (not working)
#print(l.loc[:,['s1','s2','s3']].groupby(['filter_id','tr_id']).sum(axis=1))

### sort by score
#l.sort_values(by=['score'],inplace=True)

for ((date,filter,tr),g) in l.loc[:,['s1','s2','s3']].groupby(['adate','filter_id','tr_id']):
        print(g.sum(axis=1))
```

The conditions themselves are preliminary - I need to find out good values ​​and criteria in the future ... (if you have tips in this direction, I wouldn't mind :-), but they are not the focus of this question)

thank you for your help :-)
Phil

Answer (score 0):

solved it with assign:

```py
#[...]
l['s1']=(l['aavg_diff'].abs() > 0.1).astype(int)
l['s2']=(l['aavg_pctc'].abs() > 0.01).astype(int)
l['s3']=(((l['aavg_r5']-l['aavg'])/l['aavg_r5']).abs() > .1).astype(int)

l=l.assign(score=lambda x: x.s1+x.s2+x.s3)

#[...]
```